# Installed Visual Studio 2010 and I can only choose .NET 4 as my target framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

Why can I only choose the 4.0 version of the .NET framework?

[image]

Do I need to download something extra in order to target .NET 2, 3, 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the ehh in your case [Más versiones de .NetFramework...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/netframework/aa569263.aspx) link it will point you to the microsoft resource where you can download previous versions of the .Net Framework. When you installed them, you can choose them.